# Chrome's firebug's technic to track ajax requests

Tags: javascript, ajax, google-chrome-extension, firebug, google-chrome-devtools

I'm trying to make my google chrome extension to track ajax requests while browsing web. Only way i found is to listen for DOMSubtreeModified event. Event is fired on every single ajax event but there is no additional information about the request. But in Firebug google chrome extension there is ajax requests tracking with many details. I tried to check how they do it in the source code but it's hard for me to understand.

Do You know how to track those events to get some details about request?
Maybe someone could take a look at this firebug's technic or maybe someone knows it and could tell me how they do it?

Comment: did u finally get any programmatic way to intercept Ajax requests?

Answer (score 9):

There's a few things you can do with the Chrome Developer Tools for debugging AJAX requests:

1. Look at the [network tab](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/network). It tracks all (AJAX) requests, their request and response headers.
2. Enable XHR console logging in the devtools (right-click in the Developer Tools console, and click "Enable XMLHttpRequest logging".
3. Set an [XHR breakpoint](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/javascript-debugging#breakpoints-on-xhr).

There's no need for DOM breakpoints in your case. Plus that approach would only work if your AJAX request modifies the DOM tree.

Comment: But i want to handle those ajax events in the extension's code. Extension has to send inormation about such request to my server. In chrome developer tools i can only look at it. Do you have some idea?

Comment: So? You can do the same thing.

Comment: But how? Could you post some code that I could put into my extension to handle ajax events?

Comment: In a content script it's identical to debugging AJAX in the page. In a background page, you need to first open the background page in the devtools. Go to `chrome://extensions`.

Comment: Ok, but there i can only look at them. I want to programatically handle them. For example if someone is browsing internet with this extension installed every ajax request is handled inside the extension and some information about every request is sent to my server.

Answer (score 0):

Currently there is no way of programmatically getting all info about ajax requests similar to Network tab.

There is experimental [`chrome.experimental.webRequest.onCompleted.addListener`](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/dev/experimental.webRequest.html#event-onCompleted), with it you can catch ajax request, get returned response code (200,404), and get some response headers. You won't be able to get response body.

Comment: I've seen it. Thanks for details on how it works i'll probably try this. But do you know what are possible threats related to using this experimental api? Is it unstable?

Comment: @Luke The biggest one is that you cannot submit your extension into gallery. And there is no guarantee that this method will stay in API.

Comment: That hurts.. Everybody says that there is no way to do it programmatically.  So how the hell this firebug for chrome works that it tracks ajax requests?

Comment: @Luke You mean firebug lite? I don't think it does.

Comment: Firebug lite for chrome does it indeed. I tried to understand extension source code but it's too complex for me. This is example line from firebug's console: 
POST /ajax/chat/buddy_list.php?__a=1 200 OK 202ms