# My AJAX call is only working in Internet Explorer

Tags: jquery, ajax, internet-explorer

My jQuery code is this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("input:#baglan").click(function () {
    var Type;
    var Url;
    var Data;
    var ContentType;
    var DataType;
    var ProcessData;
    WCFJSON();

    function WCFJSON() {

      var kullanici = $("input:#ad3").val();
      var sifre = $("input:#sifre").val();
      Type = "POST";
      Url = "http://hacegan:84/SQLbaglantiHACEGAN/Service.svc/GetData";
      Data = '{"value": "' + kullanici + '","sifre": "' + sifre + '"}';
      ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
      DataType = "json";
      varProcessData = true;
      CallService();
    }

    //function to call WCF  Service      
    function CallService() {
      $.ajax({
        type: Type, //GET or POST or PUT or DELETE verb
        url: Url, // Location of the service
        data: Data, //Data sent to server
        contentType: ContentType, // content type sent to server
        dataType: DataType, //Expected data format from server
        processdata: ProcessData, //True or False
        success: function (msg) { //On Successfull service call
          ServiceSucceeded(msg);
        },
        error: ServiceFailed // When Service call fails
      });
    }

    function ServiceFailed(result) {
      alert("basarisiz");
      alert('Service call failed: ' + result.status + '' + result.statusText);
      Type = null;
      varUrl = null;
      Data = null;
      ContentType = null;
      DataType = null;
      ProcessData = null;
    }

    function ServiceSucceeded(result) {
      if (DataType == "json") {
        resultObject = result.GetDataResult;
        alert(resultObject);
      }
    }


  });
```

My code is running on İnternet Explorer, but when I will run this code on Firefox or Chrome it gives en error in the ServiceFailed function. With this code I'm accessing to a WCF service. So, how can I get it working in Firefox and Chrome?

Comment: it was an writing excaption :-) now I deleted this function , but my code isn't running on firefox or chrome

Comment: `processdata: ProcessData, //True or False` from where it gets that boolean. I think this should be `processdata: varProcessData,`

Comment: `input:#baglan`? Just go with the ID, `#baglan`. (Ditto for the others.) It looks like jQuery will just ignore the `:`; by itself as a CSS selector it is invalid, but jQuery seems to just ignore it.

Comment: Hi Jai.how can I use this line in my code. Can you Can you show

Comment: alert($("#baglan").val()) will pop up a messagebox with the current value of the element with the id of "baglan".

Comment: What error are you getting? Do you have a fiddle or a link?

Comment: No haven't a link. My error comes from ServiceFailed function.see that function I writed an error alert.it comes

Answer (score 0):

In your code, you are calling a function `ServiceFailed` if your ajax call return an error:

```
error: ServiceFailed
```

You have then two functions with same name and signature:

```
function ServiceFailed(result)
```

and

```
function ServiceFailed(xhr)
```

Using the console in Chrome or Firebug, you will be able to see your ajax call.

Take a look here: [Chrome's firebug's technic to track ajax requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7499360/chromes-firebugs-technic-to-track-ajax-requests)

A suggestions:

Instead of manually create your JSON String

```
Data = '{"value": "' + kullanici + '","sifre": "' + sifre + '"}';
```

You can create the Object and then convert it to the String:

```
JSON.stringify({value: 'foo', sifre: 'bar'})
```

Comment: JSON.stringify return a String. You can just do Data = JSON.stringify( ...), btw. you have lot of mistakes in your code, this is maybe not the most important, try to read a good book about Javascript

Answer (score 0):

I think this would be better to pass in the params:

`try putting just click in the doc ready and all the functions outside` try using this one.

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
   $("input:#baglan").click(function () {
    var Type;
    var Url;
    var Data;
    var ContentType;
    var DataType;
    var ProcessData;
    WCFJSON(Type, Url, Data, ContentType, DataType, varProcessData);
   });
 }); // <----------end of doc ready

 function WCFJSON(Type, Url, Data, ContentType, DataType, varProcessData) {
     var kullanici =$("input:#ad3").val();
     var sifre=$("input:#sifre").val();
     Type = "POST";
     Url = "http://hacegan:84/SQLbaglantiHACEGAN/Service.svc/GetData";
     Data = '{"value": "' +kullanici+ '","sifre": "' +sifre+ '"}';
     ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
     DataType = "json"; 
     varProcessData = true; 
     CallService(Type, Url, Data, ContentType, DataType, varProcessData);
 }

 //function to call WCF  Service      
 function CallService(Type, Url, Data, ContentType, DataType, varProcessData) {
    $.ajax({
    type: Type, //GET or POST or PUT or DELETE verb
    url: Url, // Location of the service
    data: Data, //Data sent to server
    contentType: ContentType, // content type sent to server
    dataType: DataType, //Expected data format from server
    processdata: varProcessData, //<--------------------------should be this
    success: function (msg) { //On Successfull service call
      ServiceSucceeded(msg);
    },
    error: ServiceFailed(err) // When Service call fails
  });
}

function ServiceFailed(result) {
  alert("basarisiz");
  alert('Service call failed: ' + result.status + '' + result.statusText);
  Type = null;
  varUrl = null;
  Data = null;
  ContentType = null;
  DataType = null;
  ProcessData = null;
}

function ServiceSucceeded(result) {
  if (DataType == "json") {
    resultObject = result.GetDataResult;
    alert(resultObject);
  }
}
```

Comment: I said it can run on internet explorer not eroor on url.

Answer (score 0):

It should be ProcessData flag instead of varProcessData

```
function WCFJSON() {

  var kullanici = $("input:#ad3").val();
  var sifre = $("input:#sifre").val();
  Type = "POST";
  Url = "http://hacegan:84/SQLbaglantiHACEGAN/Service.svc/GetData";
  Data = '{"value": "' + kullanici + '","sifre": "' + sifre + '"}';
  ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
  DataType = "json";
```

> ```
> ProcessData = true;
> ```

```
  CallService();
}
```