# Cannot pass textarea input in modal window to a PHP variable

Tags: php, javascript, html, textarea, modal-dialog

To begin, I'm working with 3 languages. HTML, Javascript and PHP. I'm unable to pass user inputted textarea text to a PHP variable which would be used as a message in an email that would be sent out. What I believe to be the problem is that my textarea is actually in a modal window and for some reason I think that is what is screwing things up.

Here is my HTML Code:

```
<form name="rejectForm" action="">

<div class="rejectModal" title="rejectModal" id="rejectModal" style="display: none; padding:15px ">          

     <b> Text in the modal window</b>
     <center>              
     <textarea id="rejectArea" name="rejectArea" value="{$rejectAreaNote}" rows="6" cols="43"/>    </textarea> 
     </center>
    <br/>
    <center>

     <input type="button" value="Reject" class="btn success id="submitReject""     id="btnRejectDocumentModal" name="Reject" />    

     <input class="btn" type="reset" value="Cancel" id="btnCancelSaveModal"  />
</center><br/><br/>
</div>
</form>
</div>
```

JS Code:

```
$(function() {  
    $(".submitReject").click(function() {  
        // validate and process form here  
        $('.error').hide();  
        var rejectAreaNote = $("textarea#rejectArea").val();  
        var noteLength = rejectAreaNote.length;
        if (rejectAreaNote == "" || noteLength < 5) {  
            $("label#rejectArea_error").show();  
            $("textarea#rejectArea").focus();  
            return false;  
        }  
        var dataString = rejectAreaNote;  

        alert (dataString);return false;  

        $.ajax({  
            type: "POST",  
            url: "gs_ViewDocument.php",  
            data: dataString,  
            success: function() {  
                $('#reject_form').html("<div id='message'></div>");  
                $('#message').html("Reject Form Submitted!");
            }  
        });  
        return false;  
     });  
 });
```

What creates the Modal (JS):

```
    $('.rejectModal').css("background", "lightblue");
          $('#btnRejectDocument').bind(isTouchScreen ? "touchstart" : "click", function(){
       if (!gsSelection.unselectElem()) return false; 
           $('.rejectModal').dialog({
           modal:true, 
           resizable:false,
        width: 400,
    }).removeClass("ui-widget-content");
    $(".ui-dialog-titlebar").hide();
    return;
 });
$('#btnRejectDocumentModal').bind(isTouchScreen ? "touchstart" : "click", function(){
   $(this).parents('div.rejectModal').dialog('close');
});
$('#btnCancelSaveModal').bind(isTouchScreen ? "touchstart" : "click", function(){
   $(this).parents('div.rejectModal').dialog('close');
});
```

PHP Code:

```
if(isset($_POST['Reject'])&&$_POST['Reject']=='Reject')     
 {
      $isReject = true;
      RejectAction($DocumentID, $ClientName, $ClientEmail);
      $smartyvalues["isReject"] = $isReject;
      $smartyvalues["RejectMsg"] = "The document invitation was successfully rejected!";
 }
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: what exactly is not working here? If you are using Firefox then can you track the AJAX request using firebug to see if the POST data is actually going to the PHP page ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7499360/chromes-firebugs-technic-to-track-ajax-requests

Comment: So as it turns out the POST data is not going through to the PHP page.

Answer (score 0):

I formated your JS code and I see `return false;` before `$.ajax(...)` so your ajax will never run.

Comment: I agree. I think this could be the problem.