# Form Captcha AJAX (jQuery & PHP) how to trace an error?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm learning jQuery & PHP, and in doing so, I've got several different forms that I'm effectively trying to mash together. So the form is very simple, but has an AJAX Captcha component, that always returns an error at the moment!

Without posting the code, I'm actually more interested in how to begin to trace the problem, rather than just straight out ask for someone else to resolve it!

...so in the jQ, the data is using .serialize(), and then $.post; I pretty much get this part. Previously I had some PHP form processor that used the $_POST data to write values to a CSV file, but now this isn't working due to the data being serialized. So I have found and employed this technique:

```
$serializedData = $_POST['data'];
$unserializedData = array();
parse_str($serializedData,$unserializedData);
```

and then my CSV write code follows, but I'm always getting a negative response (and the Captcha is correct!) so where/how can I see the values that are causing the problem?

Any suggestions greatly appreciated? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download the Firebug extension on either Firefox or Chrome and follow the comments in this post:
[Chrome's firebug's technic to track ajax requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7499360/chromes-firebugs-technic-to-track-ajax-requests)